# Scheduling/scripting with Play Framework (or non-rails project) in Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

Well, my head is spinning a bit here. I started with what i thought would be a simple task, to take regular db dumps on heroku and push them to a personal S3 account for backup.

I am not sure the best a approach to do this. Accessing S3 within Java is crystal clear, getting the db dump from heroku is clear as mud right now...

Disclaimer: i don't know Ruby, and i don't really want to learn Ruby if i don't have to, i really want to use Java (that is why i chose play) and i want to have it hosted, that is why i chose Heroku :-)

So, I could use the heroku Scheduler, but i am not understanding what scripts are being executed here - is it all scripts in /bin? What kind of scripts are these, are they ruby scripts? How do i add them as 'tasks' when they aren't rake tasks?

Can I use the pgbackups via URL somehow? It looks like the rake examples do pg_dump instead, write to a tmp file and then move it around from there. I'm pretty unclear how to access the heroku databased stuff from a script, the examples i have seen so far are in rake, so any insight there would be helpful...

Or coming at it from inside my java app, what is the status of the Heroku java API? If there is a way to get to the heroku runtime from my java, or somehow use the heroku.jar?

It would great to get some overall guidance and best practices in this area - thanks!!!

Comment: This is a good question that I don't have a good answer for.  But there might be another approach that would work.  Are you using the shared-database add-on?  If so, you might want to switch to using the postgres.heroku.com database instead.  They have a [dev plan](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/) and a number of features that provide a better way to do this.

Comment: I am on a shared database. Right now when i run Heroku run Bash, i don't seem to have access to pg_dump. This seems odd since the rake tasks i have seen for ruby apps is called pg_dump. I think with this last piece of the puzzle, i could get something working...

Comment: You can use `heroku run bash` to see what is on the dyno system.

Comment: I've just put together a little Play 2 app that has a Job that can be run as a one-off process or from the Heroku Scheduler add-on: https://github.com/jamesward/play2-scheduled-job-demo  Hopefully that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the great example! I think i this question is well answered, but not sure how to vote you credit from this comment - anyway - that's my intention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the google group i found this tidbit:
http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/browse_thread/thread/7fe984c3d2d01f21/9474f31138636332?lnk=gst&q=scheduler+#9474f31138636332

"Sorry for the delayed response. We updated the docs to mention running Procfile entries via `heroku run`:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps

**Anything that works via `heroku run` works via Heroku Scheduler**. Just put the name of the process type as the 'task" in Scheduler. No special syntax required. And you can even pass it arguments. "

From this and **James Ward's last example above** i am considering this answered.